# How to calculate Input backoff per carrier of a satellite

Tags: rf, communication, antenna, microwave

I was trying to calculate the sizing of SSPA in my satcom network where input backoff per carrier is required to calculate Power flux density. 
My current network configuration in C band is 
Total carriers=15
SFD of satellite=-85dbW/m<sup>2</sup>

Please help me how to calculate input backoff per carrier.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that backoff is a variable parameter provided by the network as part of closed loop power control. For link budget design, assume that backoff is zero and design for the maximum allowed transmit power as given in the system specification.

If you provide details of the system it might be possible to give you a more specific answer. Is it BGAN, global xpress, dvbs2, etc